# TestFlight Beta app review

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, appstore-approval, testflight

If we are using `TestFlight Beta Testing Tool` for testing, It has a beta app review stage where the the Apple team performs the review of the app.

If the app gets passed in the app beta review, what are the chances that the app gets cleared in the final app review from the Apple so that it can be published to the AppStore.

Is the beta app review really helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share recent experience, my app recent built passed TestFlight beta review (usually takes a day or so ) but it failed apple submission process (after 8 days in waiting).

They both seems to be completely independent review process, and TestFlight beta review process seems to be have no effect on default apple submission review process.

Answer (score -2):

You are confused with the TestFlight beta review process.

TestFlight Beta Testing is to release a beta version of App to testers (which you can pre-register their email in iTunes Connect), not to Apple. Quoted from the official documentation (the reference link at the bottom):

> With TestFlight beta testing, you can distribute prerelease builds of
>   your app to testers to collect feedback and prepare your app for
>   release in the App Store. TestFlight beta testing is optional; you can
>   submit your app for review without using it. However, it’s easy to do,
>   free, and a valuable way to improve your app before releasing it in
>   the App Store. TestFlight beta testing in iTunes Connect is available
>   only for iOS apps. You can enable TestFlight beta testing for up to 10
>   apps at one time in your developer account. See TestFlight Beta
>   Testing in the developer portal.

Reference: [TestFlight Beta Testing (Optional)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is, if my app gets cleared in the beta app review process, what are the chances that it will be rejected in the final app review of Apple. Is the final App Review process of Apple and the Beta App Review process of Apple based on the same iOS guidelines? Or is it different? Will the Beta App Review process help me in finding out issues beforehand, which may later on be pointed out in the final App Review process by Apple.

Comment: i think Apple won't look into beta testing results at all ( Apple won't have so much free time to do so )